# ERROR Message- "Foreign Key '... ' references invalid column '...' in referencing table '... '." SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and trying to add a foreign key to the "Orders" table that references the primary key in my "Customer" table. I keep getting this message:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
> Foreign key 'orders_customerid_fk' references invalid column 'CustomerID' in referencing table 'Orders'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 28
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    fName   varchar(40),
    lName   varchar(40),
    City    varchar(40),
    Country varchar(40),
    Phone   varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier
(
    SupplierID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyName  varchar(40),
    ContactName  varchar(50),
    ContactTitle varchar(40),
    City         varchar(40),
    Country      varchar(40),
    Phone        varchar(30),
    Fax          varchar(30),
);

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderDate     datetime,
    OrderNumber   varchar(10),
    TotalAmount   decimal(12,2)
);
        
ALTER TABLE Orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT Orders_CustomerID_FK
        FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID);
```

Comment: You need to add a `CustomerID` column to the Orders table before you can create the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the column that should receive the constrain of FK.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
  ADD CustomerID INT NULL; /*Adds a new int column existing rows will be 
                     given a NULL value for the new column*/
```

Or

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
  ADD CustomerID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0);
```

And then you can

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT Orders_CustomerID_FK
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID)
            REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
;
```